# ASP.NET 4.0 application cannot find Default.aspx under IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, asp.net-4.0, default-document

I've got an ASP.NET 4.0 web application (webforms, not mvc; asp.net routing isn't used) that runs fine under IIS7. When I try to run it under IIS6 and navigate to `http://localhost/MyApp/`, I get the following exception:

```
File does not exist.
System.Web.HttpException
 at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response) (+0 IL, +2509040 JIT)
 at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath) (+54 IL, +198 JIT)
 at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) (+263 IL, +347 JIT)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() (+214 IL, +8967220 JIT)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) (+54 IL, +184 JIT)
```

Note that this output comes from **my own custom error page**. Thus, .NET itself is working fine. I can even remotely debug it and stuff.

Now, if I enter `http://localhost/MyApp/Default.aspx`, all works fine, I get the default page, etcetera. The first thought would be that the default document isn't specified in IIS, but it is. Even worse - if I disable it altogether, I still get the same error message (and yes, I restarted IIS and cleared my browser cache)!

It seems as if the request for `/` is always sent directly to ASP.NET which then gets confused because it doesn't have any default document concept. But I don't have any wildcard mappings defined, so how can that be?

Comment: Did u check direcory browsing in the Directory tab

Comment: @moguzalp - I don't want people to be able to list the contents of my directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Googling I found this one as a solution. Its unrelated but some commented its working.
Can you please try this.

In the Windows registry, open the following node: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0

1.Create a new DWORD value named EnableExtensionlessUrls.
2.Set EnableExtensionlessUrls to 0. This disables extensionless URL behavior.
3.Save the registry value and close the registry editor.
4.Run the iisreset command-line tool, which causes IIS to read the new registry value

Comment: That's a global solution for a local problem. I don't want to do this on client machines because they might need it. Still... it does seem that this is the root of the issue...

Comment: I accepted your answer because it is obviously the source of the problem. I won't set the registry key, but knowing what has caused it will allow me to write a workaround in my app.